# Vue doesn't load javascript files inside main.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I've been trying to load Javascript files inside my **VUE** project in multiple ways but nearly any way I have tried the code wouldn't work correct.

**What I have done so far:**

1. Run NPM command: vue create client.
2. Add vue-router to package.json.
3. Create Home.vue file and add it to the router.js file.
4. Move Javascript and Css files to src/assets
5. Import Css styles inside the App.vue file.
6. Required Javascript files inside the main.js file.

**Example of the main.js file:**

```
import Vue from "vue";
import App from "./App.vue";
import router from "./router";

require("./assets/js/utils/app.js");
require("./assets/js/utils/page-loader.js");
require("./assets/js/vendor/simplebar.min.js");
require("./assets/js/utils/liquidify.js");
require("./assets/js/vendor/xm_plugins.min.js");
require("./assets/js/global/global.hexagons.js");
require("./assets/js/global/global.tooltips.js");
require("./assets/js/header/header.js");
require("./assets/js/sidebar/sidebar.js");
require("./assets/js/content/content.js");
require("./assets/js/form/form.utils.js");
require("./assets/js/utils/svg-loader.js");

Vue.config.productionTip = false;

new Vue({
  router,
  render: (h) => h(App),
}).$mount("#app");
```

This way I receive the following error message:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'createHexagon' of undefined
    at eval (global.hexagons.js?f18d:4)
    at Object../src/assets/js/global/global.hexagons.js (app.js:1484)
    at __webpack_require__ (app.js:849)
    at fn (app.js:151)
    at eval (main.js?56d7:10)
    at Module../src/main.js (app.js:1632)
    at __webpack_require__ (app.js:849)
    at fn (app.js:151)
    at Object.1 (app.js:1657)
    at __webpack_require__ (app.js:849)
```

So I tested to use the following npm module: `vue-plugin-load-script`. I have copied the js folder from src/assets/js to the public folder and changed my main.js file to look like this:

```
import Vue from "vue";
import App from "./App.vue";
import router from "./router";

import LoadScript from "vue-plugin-load-script";

Vue.use(LoadScript);

Vue.loadScript("js/utils/app.js");
Vue.loadScript("js/utils/page-loader.js");
Vue.loadScript("js/vendor/simplebar.min.js");
Vue.loadScript("js/utils/liquidify.js");
Vue.loadScript("js/vendor/xm_plugins.min.js");
Vue.loadScript("js/global/global.hexagons.js");
Vue.loadScript("js/global/global.tooltips.js");
Vue.loadScript("js/header/header.js");
Vue.loadScript("js/sidebar/sidebar.js");
Vue.loadScript("js/content/content.js");
Vue.loadScript("js/form/form.utils.js");
Vue.loadScript("js/utils/svg-loader.js");

Vue.config.productionTip = false;

new Vue({
  router,
  render: (h) => h(App),
}).$mount("#app");
```

Now the Javascript files would load sometimes. For example I refreshed the site 5 times the result would look like this:

[Gif Image showing the loading](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IDiRM.gif)

As can be seen the javascript files would only load half of the time using this method. I would appreciate any kind of help and suggestions.

Comment: It's unclear if you expect scripts to be loaded before app initialization or after. It's likely the latter but this should be specified explicitly. Any way, combining Vue app with global script is a mistake, this is not how Vue apps are supposed to work. This will result in memory leaks and unexpected app behaviour.

Comment: Later yes, so it would be better to load those scripts inside the vue files itself instead of using the main.js?

Comment: Yes. Load the scripts inside the component they rely on. There can still be problems if the component renders asynchronously.